# Run Web Application on Glassfish with newer version of jna library

Tags: java, glassfish, classloader, jna, waffle

I hava a web application that should run on `glassfish`.

The application uses `jna` version `4.1.0` and the `jna-4.1.0.jar` is packed with the application inside its `lib` folder.

Howerver, as far as I can tell the `glassfish` itself uses version `3.1` of the `jna` library and it is packed inside 
`ibpam4j-repackaged.jar` on the following path:

`('C:/Program Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules')`.

As a result - the application is not running, and it throws

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Pointer.getWideString(J)Ljava/lang/String;`

cause the wrong version of the library is being used.

Any Ideas how to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

(By the way it is not my application per se - I am just trying to run a [waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) example on glassfish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that setting 
`<class-loader delegate="false"/>`
inside the **`glassfish-web.xml`** does the trick.

Everything works now.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could please specify the path of that file ?

Comment: @AniketWarey 'glassfish-web.xml' is usually inside the  'web-inf' directory of your web project.

Comment: Thanks , in my case it was 'sun-web.xml' , and it didn't had that property , so I had to add it manually :  <class-loader delegate="false"/>